# Formatting Appendix

Tags: appendices, appendix

I'm having trouble with my appendix.
It shows something like "A {my input}", "B {my input}" and so on.
I want to format it them as "Appendix {input or number}".
How can I do it?

I am only using

```
\appendix
```

for my appendix section.